# output is tuple like [{a:b, d:c,....},{a:f, b:q,...},{a:v, b:k,....},...]

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

Using mySQL I am running this: (Getting data and looping it through a table)

users is the table. The console is outputting a tuple.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com", "username", "password", "username$database")
cursor = db.cursor()    
cursor.execute('SELECT uid, firstname, lastname, username, city, state, streetaddress, email, special_needs, phonenumber, zipcode FROM users')
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

I am getting this back:

```
[{'special_needs': 'N/A', 'phonenumber': '5555555555', 'city': 'Oakland', 'zipcode': '44444', 'streetaddress': '32323 Apple St.', 'state': 'CA', 'email': 'bernie@taylor.com', 'uid': 1, 'firstname': 'Bernie', 'lastname': 'Sanders', 'username': 'bernieswift'}, {'special_needs': 'N/A', 'phonenumber': '6666666666', 'city': 'Greenappple', 'zipcode': '77777', 'streetaddress': '24936 Calaroga Ave.', 'state': 'CA', 'email': 'green@grass.com', 'uid': 2, 'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'lost', 'username': 'tony'}]
```

What I was doing before: ( this works locally )

```
print_str = "<table>"
for result in results:
print_str += "<tr><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><td> %s <br></td><tr>" % (result['uid'], result['firstname'], result['lastname'], result['username'], result['city'], result['state'], result['streetaddress'], result['email'], result['special_needs'], result['phonenumber'], result['zipcode'])
    print_str += "</table>"
```

How do I get specific values for uid, firstname, etc? (assuming I want to iterate through the whole database) How do I get the individual values from the database? I'm really confused by tuple.

Comment: Do you mean how to access them from the values returned or just the values from the database?

Comment: How to access the values from the database

Comment: I've not seen them returned like that before - Are you storing them in individual columns and rows? (fyi not me down voting you)

Comment: yes - if I am interpreting you correctly. I don't care about downvotes.. I'm new are they important?

Comment: Do you have something like this: `MySQLdb.connect(user='joe', passwd='password', db='dbname',
                      cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)`

Comment: I added it above

Comment: What about creating the table - have to specified `DictCursor` anywhere

Comment: Oh, I see how I lost it. thank you! I rewrote my database stuff for pythonprogramming.

Comment: Was it the dict cursor?

Comment: Yea it was dict cursor! Thanks!

Comment: Great. Added answer please accept

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this.
for example, you want firstname where uid is equal to 1

`uname = [counter['firsname'] for counter in result if counter['uid'] == 1]`
which returns `['Bernie']`

This works with more complicated statements for example:

`data = [(counter['firstname'],counter['lastname']) for counter in result if counter['city'] in ['Oakland', 'Greenappple']]`

returns
`[('Bernie', 'Sanders'), ('john', 'lost')]`

Although this is not the perfect solution it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise your database removing DictCursor.

You will have something like the following:

```
`MySQLdb.connect(user='joe', passwd='password', db='dbname',
                      cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)`
```